# enable Binary logging in mysql 5.7.26

Tags: mysql, configuration

I have made some changes in my `/etc/my.cnf` to turn `ON` `log_bin`. I then rebooted the server. But when I do `SHOW VARIABLES`, the `log_bin` is still turned off. This means that mysql is not using `/etc/my.cnf`. Hence, I did `locate my.cnf` and there are no more paths for the file.

How can I turn on `log_bin`?

EDIT:
When I did `sudo docker container ps`, I can see a MYSQL image:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  
asdshg3   mysql/mysql-server:5.7   "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"
```

I think this is the reason why my `/etc/my.cnf` is not getting picked up.

Comment: are you in the section `[mysqld]` else you should show us the cnf file

Comment: Yes, but I found that there was a docker container which is running mysql. I think this is the reason why `/etc/my.cnf` is not getting picked up.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648821/how-can-i-enable-mysql-binary-logging-using-the-official-docker-image